# Why $\det J_\varphi(x)=0$ for all $x$ if $\varphi:U\to \mathbb R^N$ is $\mathcal C^1$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V\subset \mathbb R^m$ open, $m<n$ and $U=V\times \mathbb R^{N-m}$. Let $\psi: V\to \mathbb R^N$ is $\mathcal C^1$. We define $$\varphi(x_1,...,x_N)=\psi(x_1,...,x_m),\quad (x_1,...,x_N)\in U.$$

Why $\varphi: U\to \mathbb R^N$ is $\mathcal C^1$ and why $$\det J_\varphi(x)=0$$ for all $x\in U$ ?

I think the fact that $\varphi$ is $\mathcal C^1$ comme from the fact that the projection : $$p:U\to V$$
defined by $p(x_1,...,x_n)=(x_1,...,x_n)$ is $\mathcal C^1$. Now, $\varphi=\psi\circ p$, therefore $$J_\varphi(x)=J_\psi(p(x))J_{p}(x)^T.$$
Why does $$\det J_\varphi(x)=0 \ \ ?$$

Comment: $J_{\phi} (x)$ always has zero columns [or rows, depend on your notation choice].

Comment: Looks like $n$ turned into $N;$ confusing.

Comment: @xbh You should post that as answer, it's a simple way to see it.

Answer (score 1):

From the chain rule, $J_{\phi}(x) = J_{\psi}(p(x))J_{p}(x)$.  This $J_{\phi}(x) $ is an $n\times n$ matrix representing a map $\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$.  $J_{\psi}(p(x))$ is a map $\mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $J_{p}(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$.  The maximum rank of the product $J_{\psi}(x)J_{p}(x)$ is $m$, so the product is singular.

Comment: $p:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ therefore $J_p$ is not a square matrix, and thus $\det J_p$ is not defined.

Comment: I think you meant to define $p(x_{1},...,x_{n}) = (x_{1},...,x_{m})$ then in your discussion.